# validation of textbox in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, regex

1. How to validate that a textbox should contain only alphabets 
   using javascript or using regular expression?

Comment: This question is quite simple but i am getting some difficulty.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: "using javascript or using regular expression"? So you want any method in the JavaScript language or a regular expression method in any language (or Java since you have tagged the question that way)? I'm guessing you don't mean "or", you might want to edit the question.

Comment: The question has been resolved. Thanx everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Regex in JavaScript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) to achieve this...

```
var text = document.getElementById('TEXTBOX_ID').value;//get value from textbox
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;//only allow letters (minimum of 1). No whitespace, no symbols, no numbers

if(regex.test(text)){
   //this is valid
}
```

Comment: That won't work. You haven't bound the regular expression to the start of the string. You have a random space before your attempt to call the test method. You don't address the "a textbox" part of the question.

Comment: @Quentin: First two points are typing errors. The 3rd has been addressed

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cek = /^[a-zA-Z\ \']+$/;
function validate(form){
var name = form.name.value;
 if (!cek.test(name)) {
  alert("Only Alphabetic");
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}
</script>

<form method="" action="#" onSubmit="return validate(this);" name="form">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a function:

```
function validateTextbox(element) {

    var pattern = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

    if (!pattern.test(element.innerHTML) {

        //Do something
        element.innerHTML += " Not matched";

    }

}
```

Bind it to the element:

```
<some-element onchange="validateTextbox(this)" />
```

Or bind it using (the easier to maintain and recommended) way:

```
var element = getElementById("someID");
element.addEventListener("change", function() {

        var pattern = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

        if (!pattern.test(element.innerHTML) {

            //Do something
            element.innerHTML += " Not matched";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't work. You shouldn't be using innerHTML to test the value of a textbox, and your regular expression will match absolutely everything (since it tests to see if a string contains zero or more of certain characters, which all strings will). Intrinsic event handler attributes should be avoided too. It is considered good coding style to not depend on semi-colon insertion.

Comment: Oh, and `element.innerHtml` will always be `undefined` unless something is explicitly assigned to it. JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typos (the semi-colons and innerHTML). As far as the regexp goes, I took for granted he wanted to match the empty string, A-Z and space *0 or more times*.

Comment: The question doesn't say space, and that will match "£%@^$£^" since it is a string that includes 0 letters.